# Downgrading Google Chrome version after disabling auto updates

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google

I wish to keep using a particular version of Google Chrome macOS app. I have used [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7812708?answerId=32299371022#32299371022) link to stop Google Chrome macOS app from auto updating. But, the problem is that I stopped auto updates while running version 75.

I need to run version 70. I am also unable to revert back the changes which I made.

Could anyone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Hey There! https://omahaproxy.appspot.com 70.0.3538.77 was available! https://superuser.com/questions/936432/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-chrome

Comment: I got  Branch Base Position: 587811 which I searched on https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/587811/ mentioned by you and downloaded chrome-mac.zip file but I am getting a popup “Chromium” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.

Comment: You can go to system preferences-> security and allow it to open. I think there might be some risks involved. On chrome forums, they use oldapps.com. Also on some answers, I read about deleting previous data from Library. I suggest you cut paste it somewhere and then install the older version. At least you’ll have backup of newer version.

Comment: Google directory under Library is empty and I tried to search allow option for chrome didn't find one under system preferences.

Comment: `/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` it is here. Also System Preferences-> security and privacy-> general tab.

Answer (score 0):

Download an older Chrome version from [slimjet.com](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php), or [en.uoldown.com](https://en.uoldown.com/mac/google-chrome/versions) and move it to the Application folder.

Disable auto update:

1. Open the **Application** folder in the finder
2. Right-click on the **Google Chrome** app
3. Select **Show Packaged Content** and open the **Contents** folder
4. Open **info.plist** file with your favourite text editor
5. Search for **KSUpdateURL** and rename the string value URL to something else (127.0.0.1)